# TypeScript conditional Exclude type exclude from interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

According to documentation, I can use predefined Exclude type to exclude certain properties from certain type:

```
type Test = string | number | (() => void);

type T02 = Exclude<Test, Function>;
```

However if instead of Test type I'd have Test interface, it doesn't seems to work. How can I achieve similiar result in below case?

```
interface Test {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: () => void;
} 

// get somehow interface with excluded function properties??
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get this effect you need to figure out which properties match `Function`, and then selectively exclude them.  Equivalently we find which properties do not match `Function`, and then selectively include them.  This is more involved than just excluding some pieces of a union; it involves [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) as well as [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types).

One way to do this is as follows:

```
type ExcludeMatchingProperties<T, V> = Pick<
  T,
  { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? never : K }[keyof T]
>;

type T02 = ExcludeMatchingProperties<Test, Function>;
// type T02 = {
// a: string;
// b: number;
// }
```

---

Examining `ExcludeMatchingProperties<T, V>`, we can note that the type `{ [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? never : K }[keyof T]` will return the keys in `T` whose properties are not assignable to `V`.

If `T` is `Test` and `V` is `Function`, this becomes something like

```
{ 
  a: string extends Function ? never : "a"; 
  b: number extends Function ? never : "b"; 
  c: ()=>void extends Function ? never : "c" 
}["a"|"b"|"c"]
```

, which becomes

```
{ a: "a"; b: "b"; c: never }["a"|"b"|"c"]
```

, which becomes

```
{ a: "a"; b: "b"; c: never }["a"] | 
{ a: "a"; b: "b"; c: never }["b"] | 
{ a: "a"; b: "b"; c: never }["c"]
```

, or

```
"a" | "b" | never
```

, or

```
"a" | "b"
```

Once we have those keys, we `Pick` their properties them from `T` (using the `Pick<T, K>` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk)):

```
Pick<Test, "a" | "b">
```

which becomes the desired type

```
{
  a: string,
  b: number
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDLJwBcyWUoA5gNwHIBGpIArgLb3S2EKkAUAlMgC8APmQA3APbAAJrQC+ePGACeABxQBRAB4IANsxkQAsnDAIAFlQAKUSRqhhgmADyoANMgBqYocmvACADWLnQedDjIANoA0sigyEEQKpIwaAC6ALQA-KSosenIENqQIDIY3sjZyCAQ4tDIpHHyUUkpaajpeCK0yuooqAAMAEzCyDr6hiZmljZ2Dk6u6FieAGLMIAhOkiA9eAD0+8iqGmgjY-iHRKTkVLRXjDVsHFD3R4pAA)

Comment: Hey @jcals! Nicely done. The only case I found when it does not work - class parameters. Please take a look when you have time and let me know your thoughts https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-what-the-heck?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftypes.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts