# Exclude properties from type or interface in TypeScript for an arbitrary object

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'd like to have explicit properties excluded from type `Record<string, unknown>` for an input. I want to have a type used for an input.

```
type InputType = Omit<Record<string, unknown>, keyof AnotherType>
```

where `AnotherType` is

```
type AnotherType = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
```

How do I achieve this effect?

In essence, I want to say you can give me any object type but it should not contain these keys no matter what type of value they contain.

This `InputType` will be the type of an argument of a function which I will call later.

Would interfaces be a better approach here? If it can be done with generics, that would be better.

I've looked around online and here, but my vocabulary with TypeScript is a bit lacking.

The closest thing I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384765/typescript-conditional-exclude-type-exclude-from-interface).

**===EDIT===**

This is what I have so far

```
interface AnotherType {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

interface InputType extends Record<string, unknown> {
    [key: string]: any;
    a?: never;
    b?: never;
    c?: never;
}

function foo(x: InputType) {return x}

foo({
  x : 2 // fine,
  a : "a" // error,
  a : 2 // error
})
```

But this feels hacky, I'm repeating myself, and I'm hard coding keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using an intersection with [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) mapping `AnotherType`'s keys to the value type `never` (with the optional flag):

```typescript
type AnotherType = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
type InputType = Record<string, unknown> & {
    [key in keyof AnotherType]?: never;
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−^^^^^^−−−−− optional and never
};

const x: InputType = {
    q: 42,  // <=== Okay
    a: 42,  // <=== Error
};

function example(x: InputType) {
    console.log(x);
}

example({
    q: 42,  // <=== Okay
    a: 42,  // <=== Error
});

declare let arg1: {q: number};
declare let arg2: {a: number};

example(arg1);  // <=== Okay
example(arg2);  // <=== Error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdge2ACwgJwCrmgXigbwCgoSoBDALigGdg0BLOAcwG5jSAjK2h5t0qAGNudRq0IBfQqEhQAknDABXYFll4AShEEI0AEwA8PMQBooSuAGtEAdzgA+KADIC7EgG1LEEFEZQvIAgAZrCIKOhqEAC6APxUcBAAbuj8pAD0aVCASEQ5uXn5BTkAesVFZWX5UAhgwPQIcGQANuRwelAJyWiSbIQ6cLRQAB5UCsqq2FB4RAIAjlQALABMZlAZUAY4m1AA8pZkIG7kC8skaxtbAKJoaLrdhIRBFoK19VAQg2QAtmCNEAAUw3kihUkQAlK4BH1qAhfgA6RoIJgA0FsKSEd5fH7-aakOZQJYrM6bPC7faHSj4k6rTLnPBXG5dCQo+56bSNMhoaC-YDkNBMACMVHweLgSk+HHQEjYrME7M5UG5vKYiyFFNF4slPQx31+fw5ApRpxpxJ2ewO2qxer5i0N1PWJvptyAA)

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, this is very useful. I just wanted to say while the example works as shown, if I used `InputType` to be the type of an argument in a function and called the function, I couldn't pass anything at all to the argument. I get an error like `Argument of type '{ foo: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown> & { a: never; b: never; c: never; }'.
  Type '{ foo: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ a: never; b: never; c: never; }': a, b, c`. I will edit my question to reflect this, I should have been clearer.

Comment: @StackMatch - Sorry, the `never` properties should have been optional. I've updated the answer and shown calling a function.

Comment: Thank you for providing that update. It's working as expected now. Thank you so much, this helped me out from a tight spot! I want to avoid checking keys at run time.